# How to display a 2-D matrix using surf or mesh?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, mesh, surface

Let's say I have a matrix `A`, how can I display it with `surf` or `mesh` that X-Y axies are the index of elements(e.g. `i,j`) and the Z value is the values in `A(i,j)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass it *directly* to `surf` and it will automatically use the indices as the x and y coordinates

```
data = rand(10)
surf(data);
```

> `surf(Z)` creates a three-dimensional shaded surface from the z components in matrix `Z`, using `x = 1:n` and `y = 1:m`, where `[m,n] = size(Z)`. The height, `Z`, is a single-valued function defined over a geometrically rectangular grid. `Z` specifies the color data, as well as surface height, so color is proportional to surface height. The values in `Z` can be numeric or datetime or duration values.